# What is the idiomatic way to iterate over a vector of hashmaps using flatten?

Tags: rust

I have the following `HashMap`:

```rust
let mut map = HashMap::new();
map.insert(String::from("one"), 1);
map.insert(String::from("two"), 2);
map.insert(String::from("three"), 3);
```

To iterate over the `HashMap` and count the amount of times the value is in `2`:

```rust
fn count_map(hm: &HashMap<String, i32>, v: i32) -> usize {
    hm.iter().filter(|&(_, b)| *b == v).count()
}

count_map(&map, 2)
```

If I had an additional `HashMap` and stored both of those in a vector:

```rust
let mut map = HashMap::new();
map.insert(String::from("one"), 1);
map.insert(String::from("two"), 2);
map.insert(String::from("three"), 3);

let mut map2 = HashMap::new();
map2.insert(String::from("two"), 2);
map2.insert(String::from("four"), 4);
map2.insert(String::from("six"), 6);

let vec_map = vec![map, map2];
```

How would you iterate over `vec_map` to count the amount of times the value is in `2`? I'm aware of `flatten` but not clear on how to use it.

```rust
fn count_hm_two(vec_map: &[HashMap<String, i32>], v: i32) -> usize {
    vec_map.iter()???
}
```

Comment: `vec_map.iter().map(|h| count_map(h, v)).sum()`

Comment: Use `hm.values()`  to only iterate over the values instead of `hm.iter()` which iterates over key-value tuples, where the keys get ignored in the `.filter()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Iterator::flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten) can be used to iterate over nested collections:

```rust
fn count_hm_two(hm: &[HashMap<String, i32>], v: i32) -> usize {
    hm.iter().flatten().filter(|&(_, b)| *b == v).count()
}
```

Comment: `hm.iter().map(|hm| hm.values()).flatten().filter(|&b| *b == v).count()` avoids iterating over the key-space